# Extending the solution of an ODE to the boundary of the defining interval

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

(1) Given a linear differential equation of the form
$$ a_1(t) \dot x(t) + a_0(t) x(t) + b(t) = 0,\qquad t\in \mathbb R,$$
where $a_0,a_1,b\in C^1(\mathbb R)$ are given. Suppose that $a_1$ has zeros, say exactly one, namely at $t=0$. Then, the above equation admits a unique solution $u\in C^1( (0,\infty)^2 \times \mathbb R)$ on $(0,\infty)$, i.e. $u(.,t_0,x_0)$ denotes the unique solution of the linear "initial value problem"
$$ \dot x = f(t,x),\quad x(t_0)=x_0,$$
for $t>0$, where $f(t,x) = -\frac{a_0}{a_1}(t) x - \frac{b}{a_1}(t)$.

(2) There are some cases where there is exactly one pair of initial values such that $x$ can be $C^1$-wise extended to $0$. For instance, consider the equation $ 2t \dot x = x$. Here, its solution on $(0,\infty)$ is given by $u(t,t_0,x_0) =x_0 \sqrt{\frac{t}{t_0}}$, for $t,t_0>0$, $x_0\in\mathbb R$. But only taking $x_0=0$ can guarantee a $C^1$ extension in $0$.

(3) Is there a more general treatment of this problem in the literature, perhaps with results on the possibility of extending regularly and uniquely in the sense I mentioned? Having observed the same phenomena at other points (more involved settings where uniqueness of the solution to equation (1) is known, but existence only on $(0,\infty)$), I would be interested in your views at that problem.

Comment: In case you didn't know already this is called a 'regular singularity', the general case is where you take the $n$'th derivative and the order of the zero at the origin of the function $a_k$ is at most $k$. There is a lot of literature about it, but I don't have a reference from the top of my head. Perhaps look for 'Euler's equation' for a degree 2 example

Comment: Ehm, Caucy-Euler equation is perhaps a better search term given the sheer quantity of things  named after Euler